Magnetic monopole in CPT universe model
I've recently read this paper CPT universe, and a thought came into my mind.
Is it possible to discuss magnetic monopole based on this CPT universe model?
This paper points out that some mysterious facts (like the difference amount of matter and anti-matter in our universe and so on), which makes me think of if the similar reasoning can be applied to the appearance of magnetic monopole?
The thought isn't mature so far, but I need some suggestions.
Many thanks!

Maybe you're asking if that model can also produce an asymmetry in the number of magnetic monopoles, with many on one side and few on the other side (our side)?

@MitchellPorter Yes, but I wonder if this idea is proper or not, since I know magnetic monopole is predicted in current theory, so its existence should be independent of this model?

The standard model doesn't predict monopoles. They arise in grand unified theories. So if you combine grand unification with this "CPT symmetric universe" concept (which is independent of one's choice of fundamental fields and interactions), there are probably ways to make the "universe/anti-universe" asymmetry, give rise to depletion of monopoles on one side...

For me, the main question is whether the title concept even makes sense. The string theorist @Luboš Motl wrote a rebuttal but it was lost to the Internet when he made his blog private. You can see the start of it here https://web.archive.org/web/20180401011605/https://motls.blogspot.com/ but not the actual argument.

@MitchellPorter thanks for the reply, I should think more carefully on this topic!
